# System of matrices

Tags: matrices

I'm trying to write a system of matrices, but my code is wrong (I'm using empheq):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts, empheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align}
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
    \dot{q}_1 \\
    \dot{q}_2
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
    - (k_{21} + k_{01}) & k_{12} \\
    k_{21}              & - (k_{12} + k_{02})
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    q_1 \\
    q_2
\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    0
\end{bmatrix}
u
\]

\[
\begin{bmatrix}
    y_1 \\
    y_2
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{1}{V_1} \\
    0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    q_1 \\
    q_2
\end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`empheq` starts math mode, so don't use `\[ .. \]` in addition to `empheq`. Remove all `\[` and `\]`, indicate the alignment points with an `&` before the `=` in each row, and add a linebreak with `\\` after the `u` in the first line.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts, empheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
    \dot{q}_1 \\
    \dot{q}_2
\end{bmatrix}
&= % <-- added &
\begin{bmatrix}
    - (k_{21} + k_{01}) & k_{12} \\
    k_{21}              & - (k_{12} + k_{02})
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    q_1 \\
    q_2
\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    0
\end{bmatrix}
u \\ % <-- added \\
\begin{bmatrix}
    y_1 \\
    y_2
\end{bmatrix}
&= % added &
\begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{1}{V_1} \\
    0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    q_1 \\
    q_2
\end{bmatrix}
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

Comment: amazing solution (as always)!!

Answer (score 5):

nested equations in `empheq` (actually in any math) environments is not allowed. correct code in your case is (if i understand your code correctly):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsfonts, empheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
    \dot{q}_1 \\
    \dot{q}_2
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
    - (k_{21} + k_{01}) & k_{12} \\
    k_{21}              & - (k_{12} + k_{02})
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    q_1 \\
    q_2
\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    0
\end{bmatrix}
u
\begin{bmatrix}
    y_1 \\
    y_2
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{1}{V_1} \\
    0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    q_1 \\
    q_2
\end{bmatrix}
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm up voting your answer because I wrote the question with typos. This confused the readers.